# Find out the directory where the class instance was created?

Tags: php, oop

Is it possible to know the directory where the class instance was created? The path of the directory I need to know in the class to save the result in the same directory. So far I've only come up with a "bike" transmitting:

```
(new BasicTest('test_value', dirname(__FILE__))
```

in the class constructor itself. Are there other ways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`debug_backtrace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)

```
class A {
    function __construct() {
        var_dump(dirname(debug_backtrace()[0]['file']));
    }
}
```